# Codeigniter 2 models

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, model

I've to fetch data from different web services + my own database and combining these data before displaying in the site.

What's the best method for doing this? I prefer writing separate models for web services and database. How can I organize the model classes of different data sources in different folders?

I may add more webservices later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I am Really sorry, as my example below will not work, as you cannot have equally named models. You should prefix them in the subdirectories as well, like:

1. webservice1/ws1_products
2. webservice2/ws2_products
3. db/db_products
4. products

That way you will load them as

```
$this->load->model('webservice1/ws1_products');
$this->load->model('webservice2/ws2_products');
$this->load->model('db/db_products');
$this->load->model('products');
```

And use as

```
$x = $this->ws1_products->getAll();
$x = $this->ws2_products->getAll();
$x = $this->db_products->getAll();
$x = $this->products->getAll();  // combined result
```

End of edit.

To separate them in different folders simply put them in subfolders in `models` directory, then use common syntax `$this->load->model('web_service1/products');`.

I don't know the best method, as it is a matter of preference, but if I were you, I would separate them as you said in two different models and made a third one, that would combine them to one result.
So if you have to get products from 2 different services and your database, I would make 4 models:

1. webservice1/products
2. webservice2/products
3. db/products
4. products // the model that combines them to one result

That way you would have to make only one request from the controller, to the `products` model.

Comment: Yes, the "best" way is to make a single API, then abstract out the differences in web services.

Comment: Yes, but mind the edit I've made to my answer, as I totally forgot they will have same model names, as the directories they're in are not included in their class names or CodeIgniter model instances

Answer (score 2):

I usually do one model file per data source. Be it a DB table, web service, etc.

For combining data from 2 or more models before rendering I like to do it in the controller if there is business logic involved. If not I do it right in the model (you can now load one model from another in CI2)

Comment: I would not recommend combining them in controllers, as you said, because business logic is for models, controllers are only for "what to get and what to show". If you do MVCs, you should be using their rule of "Keep models fat, controllers thin and views dumb"